# Hybridization of Atoms in a Protein (Biopython)

Tags: bioinformatics, biopython, protein-database

I want to find the hybridization of atoms (sp2, sp3) in a protein for a project. I am using biopython and I am struggling to code this. I couldn't find any existing code for this purpose. Is there an easy method to find the hybridizations?

Note: I just need the naïve hybridizations found using the number of bonds around an atom.

Comment: You might find these links helpful: 
https://www.rdkit.org/docs/RDKit_Book.html;
https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_do_I_convert_my_peptides_into_SMILES_strings

Comment: you mean after Neutron Crystallography of your proten ?

Comment: @pippo1980 I am taking data from a pdb file and processing it using biopython. Sorry but I am not aware of the technique you mentioned.

Comment: a protein is a repetition of aminoacid linked by peptide bond ( where , if I am reading it right :C and N atoms are both hybridized sp2), so you just need to look at the state of the 20aa that could compose the polipeptide chain. Not sure of what kind of resolution you need to be sure that the geometry observed in crystal is the true one (even if its agasinst the theoretical one), of course you miss the real observed positions of H atoms(not sure threy could influence hybridization of nearby orbitals) thats why in theory neutron crystallography helps because I they say it can show H atoms too.

Comment: or you can Direct Observation of Molecular Orbitals Using Synchrotron X-ray Diffraction  https://www.mdpi.com/2073-4352/10/11/998 but I don't think you can do that on proteins , oe not ?

Comment: Experimental Observation of Bonding Electrons in Proteins* https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021925819725010